# Variable globally scoped but why function unable to access?

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables

Why execution failed at first console log despite globally scoped variable exist?

```js
const message = 'starts with mssg #1'; //Global scope

function scopeTest() {
  console.log('1. test #1: ', message); // <-- why unable to read Global scope here?

  const message = 'changed to mssg #2';
  console.log('2. test #2: ', message);

  if (true) { //Code block is OK
    const message = 'changed to mssg #3';
    console.log('3. test #3: ', message);
  }

  { //Another code block is OK
    const message = 'changed to mssg #4';
    console.log('4. test #4: ', message);
  }

  console.log('5. test last: ', message);
}
scopeTest();
```

Alternative coding solution not required. Just wanted to understand **why JS can't access the global variable at the start of this particular function**.

Please shed light. Thank you

Comment: Because `const` [is hoisted in its scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone), the local `message` shadows the global one.

Comment: More useful error message in FF: "_message": "ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `message' before initialization_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in JavaScript are **hoisted** when declared. This means that even if you declare them later in the code, they will still be accessible in earlier calls: it is like the declaration (not the assignation of the value!) would’ve been written in the first line of the block where you’ve declared it.

In your code, you have declared your `message` variable in the body of the function so it is trying to access **that** one because of hoisting, instead of the one declared in the global scope.

More reading on the matter [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Answer (score 3):

Because any references to `message` inside `scopeTest` will refer to the *nearest scope which has a `message` variable declared* - that is, inside the `scopeTest` function here. At the time you try to reference it, `message` has been identified as a variable name *scoped inside of the function* (that is, when you reference it, you're referencing the local variable, not the global variable), but the local variable has not been initialized yet - the interpreter hasn't run across the `const message =` line, so the `message` variable in in the demilitarized zone, or the temporal dead zone - trying to reference it before it has been initialized will result in the error that it's not defined.

If you remove the `const message` from inside `scopeTest` (so that references to the `message` variable name will refer to the global variable), or move `const message` to *above* the `test #1` (so that it's initialized by the time you try to log it), it'll work as expected:

```js
const message = 'starts with mssg #1'; //Global scope

function scopeTest() {
  const message = 'changed to mssg #2';
  console.log('1. test #1: ', message);
}
scopeTest();
```

and

```js
const message = 'starts with mssg #1'; //Global scope

function scopeTest() {
  console.log('1. test #1: ', message);
}
scopeTest();
```